# Lucene.net query for contains and avoiding empty string fields

Tags: lucene.net

I have a Lucene index setup which I can query fine. I just am not able to get a "field not equals to empty string" condition to work. For example in the below code specimen, I want to have 3 conditions

1. Where "country tag" field contains "{4ED2F7EE-5C2A-418C-B2F6-236F94166BA1}".
2. Where "country tag" field is not empty string.
3. Where "date" range is between "20110101T000000" and "20121001T000000".

   ```
       WildcardQuery taggingQuery = new WildcardQuery(new Term("country tag", "*" + ShortID.Encode("{4ED2F7EE-5C2A-418C-B2F6-236F94166BA1}").ToLowerInvariant() + "*"));
       TermQuery taggingNotQuery = new Term("country tag", " "));

       RangeQuery rangeQuery = new RangeQuery(new Term("date", "20110101T000000"), new Term("date", "20121001T000000"), true);

       BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
       booleanQuery.Add(taggingQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
       booleanQuery.Add(taggingNotQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST_NOT);
       booleanQuery.Add(rangeQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
   ```

I have a feeling I am doing this wrong or my query is wrong somehow. I should not need a condition where I should have to look out for empty or null fields.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the code you use to write a document to the index that has no country?

Comment: Do you add the coutry tag field multiple times to your document? If no then you dont need the MUST_NOT clause. Btw your MUST_NOT checks for a space, not empty string. Finally, from what you are saying,  I'd recommend that your dont add fields with empty string, just dont add the field to your Document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should've paid more attention when setting up the index. I forgot to add field analyzers for each field. The multilist fields were getting indexed with a different analyzer instead of the standard analyzer. I added this to my config section for field crawls and my query started working

```
<fieldTypes hint="raw:AddFieldTypes">
                  <!-- Text fields need to be tokenized -->
                  <fieldType name="single-line text" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="multi-line text" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="word document" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="html" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="rich text" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="memo" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="text" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <!-- Multilist based fields need to be tokenized to support search of multiple values -->
                  <fieldType name="multilist" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="treelist" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="treelistex" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="checklist" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <!-- Legacy tree list field from ver. 5.3 -->
                  <fieldType name="tree list" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                </fieldTypes>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you allow '*' as the first character in the search string, Lucene can use queries like "countrytag:*" to find all documents that contain anything in the **countrytag** field. (Lucene's default is to disable an initial '*' in a query string.)

Comment: I tried to use WildQuery query = new WildQuery("country tag", "*[GUID]*"); but it didn't work. This query gets added to a boolean query along with other range and term queries. Also, I tried QueryParser to allow leading star but that didn't work either. 

The country tag field gets analyzed by a StandardAnalyzer and it is a string of GUID values. After analyzation it is added as "ASDF342SDFAS 2342LJLJl" with spaces in between. Mind you GUIDs are just samples. Actual values are true GUIDs without the hyphens and curly braces. I just can't get this thing to work and at my wits end right now.

Comment: Also, the value I try to search with is converted to the analyzed field format as in 23LKLL233 for example.